# htaccess 301 redirect for multiple urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**I have many urls such as:**

```
mydomain.com/location/illinois/

mydomain.com/location/wisconsin/green-bay/

mydomain.com/location/new-york/
```

I have removed the word location and replaced it with:
/blog/category/

**so those urls should now be:**

```
mydomain.com/blog/category/illinois/

mydomain.com/blog/category/wisconsin/green-bay/

mydomain.com/blog/category/new-york/
```

I am trying to get this done with one rewrite rule.  But the one I created is not working.  Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

**Here is what I tried:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/location(/.*|)$ /blog/category/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice try, you just need to drop the opening slash which is not included in .htaccess matches:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^location(/.*|)$ /blog/category$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

No need for the RewriteBase either. And you had doubled up the slash before the category which you're already capturing.

Comment: Thank you.  Out of curiosity, how is this kind of rewrite different than something like: RedirectMatch 301 /location/(.*) /blog/category/$1

Comment: In that example it's not really different, apart from the affect of the flags and when it is processed. mod_rewrite is just a much more powerful system with many more possibilities than RedirectMatch. In this case they can both do the job.